# Listening for events in react native ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I cannot for the life of me get an event to properly send from iOS native across the bridge to the react native JS context. On the Objective-C side I want to have a module to easily send events across the bridge. I have called this class EventEmitter and its definition is as follows:

```
// EventEmitter.h

#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"

@interface EventEmitter : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

  - (void)emitEvent:(NSString *) eventName withData:(id) eventData;

@end
```

and the implementation:

```
// EventEmitter.m

#import "EventEmitter.h"

@implementation EventEmitter

  RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

  @synthesize bridge = _bridge;

  - (void)emitEvent:(NSString *) eventName withData:(id) eventData
  {
    NSLog( @"emitting %@ with data %@", eventName, [eventData description] );
    [[_bridge eventDispatcher] sendDeviceEventWithName:eventName body:eventData];
    [[_bridge eventDispatcher] sendAppEventWithName:eventName body:eventData];
  }

@end
```

I'm using both sendDeviceEvent and sendAppEvent because I can't get either to work.

On the JS side of things I register to receive these events in the global namespace of one of my modules (so that I know the event subscription will happen before the event is emitted). I register like this:

```
console.log( 'ADDING EVENT LISTENERS' );
NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener( 'blah', test => console.log( 'TEST1', test ) );
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener( 'blah', test => console.log( 'TEST2', test ) );
```

In my log statements I get the following:

```
2016-03-19 12:26:42.501 [trace][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] ADDING EVENT LISTENERS
2016-03-19 12:26:43.613 [name redacted][348:38737] emitting blah with data [data redacted]
```

So I can tell that I am sending both an app event and a device event with the tag blah and I have registered to listen for the blah event with both the DeviceEventEmitter and NativeAppEventEmitters but I'm not getting called back in the listeners.

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks for reading!

Comment: At a first glance this looks OK. DeviceEventEmitter is exposed in react-native.js. Looking at the AppState module for example: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/ad8a33586410c6f9048983f64f8f86e0715e73b8/Libraries/AppState/AppState.js

What you could try is find a 3rd-party module that emits events and look at its code: https://js.coach/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Martin. I have been looking around for examples that use either NativeAppEventEmitter or DeviceEventEmitter and everything they do seems the same as what I have. The only thing I can think of is that because I have EventEmitter as its own class, I'm doing a standard alloc/init to get an instance of it before I can access the emitEvent method. Would the fact that I'm just allocating it on my own terms have any effect?

Comment: Are you creating new EventEmitter instances by [EventEmitter alloc] init] ? If so, can you debug the value of _bridge in emitEvent method?

Comment: I think the problem is that your EventEmitter class doesn't have a reference to the bridge. The `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE` macro is made to export native modules to javascript and instances of these classes should not be created manually. If you want to have a helper to send events to JS maybe you could make something like a singleton and pass it a reference to the bridge in your AppDelegate.

Comment: Yeah it's correct that the _bridge was null; however, I'm not sure how I can go about getting one now. I've moved the emitEvent logic from a helper class to my AppDelegate but my AppDelegate also does not have a valid _bridge. Any suggestions? My use case is to emit a registration token for GCM (rather than a device token for APNS in which case I would just use PushNotificationIOS) so I need to be able to do everything from the native side

Comment: Actually looking at PushNotificationIOS I see that the SetBridge is adding selectors for the events that will be emitted and adding itself as an observer. Should I be implementing this method? My concern is that this means I will have to predefine all events that will be emitted which is not an issue per se but would be nice not to have to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried dispatching events and it seems `bridge` is not initialised when you create new `EventEmitter` instances manually by using `[EventEmitter alloc] init]`

You should let react-native create instances. I checked native components and they're using `-(void)setBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge` method to do initialisation work. Please check out `RCTLinkingManager` to see an example. It's using `NSNotificationCenter` to handle events.

```
// registering for RCTOpenURLNotification evet when the module is initialised with a bridge
- (void)setBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  _bridge = bridge;

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(handleOpenURLNotification:)
                                               name:RCTOpenURLNotification
                                             object:nil];
}

// emitting openURL event to javascript
- (void)handleOpenURLNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [_bridge.eventDispatcher sendDeviceEventWithName:@"openURL"
                                              body:notification.userInfo];
}

// creating RCTOpenURLNotification event to invoke handleOpenURLNotification method
+ (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)URL
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
  NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *payload = @{@"url": URL.absoluteString};
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:RCTOpenURLNotification
                                                      object:self
                                                    userInfo:payload];
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can using `NativeEventEmitter`

```
// register eventEmitter
    const {NGListener} = NativeModules; // NSListener is my class
    this.eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.NGListener);   
    this.eventEmitter.addListener('CancelEvent', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
```

In ObjectiveC , you can create

```
    #import <RCTViewManager.h>
    #import <RCTEventEmitter.h>
    @interface NGListener: RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
    @end

    @implementation NGListener

    RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

    - (NSArray<NSString*> *)supportedEvents {
        return @[@"CancelEvent", @"OKEvent"];
    }
    // And you sent event you want from objectC to react-native
    [self sendEventWithName:@"CancelEvent" body:@"Tap`enter code here` on Cancel button      from Objc"];
```

I wrote sample example to handle event from react-native to objectivec and opposite.
https://github.com/lengocgiang/event-listener
Hope this help!!

Comment: Does it matter what order each `init` is? The ReactNative part of the Obj-C part?

Comment: Hmm. I'm close. I got this error `Error when sending event: StatusBarTap with body: . Bridge is not set. This is probably because you've explicitly synthesized the bridge in StatusBarTap, even though it's inherited from RCTEventEmitter.`

Comment: too much old code, I don't think it is supported now

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got this working by keeping a value of the bridge from RCTRootView and passing it to the Emitter Instance.

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
  RCTBridge *rootBridge;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  ......

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"MyApp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootBridge = rootView.bridge;

  .......

}

- (IBAction)doAction:(id)sender {
  BridgeEvents *events = [[BridgeEvents alloc] init];
  [events setBridge:rootBridge];
  [events doMyAction];
}
```

In my Emitter Class:

```
#import "RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface BridgeEvents : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
- (void)doMyAction;
@end

#import "BridgeEvents.h"

@implementation BridgeEvents

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[@"onEvent"];
}

- (void)doMyAction {
  [self sendEventWithName:@"onEvent" body:@""];
}

@end
```

Comment: After the whole day browsing for a solution, this one saved me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

RNNotification *notification = [RNNotification allocWithZone: nil];
[notification sendNotificationToReactNative]I tried everything above and was not able to get it work in my app.

Finally [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15421) worked for me.

```
#import "RNNotification.h"
@implementation RNNotification

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    static RNNotification *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents
{
    return @[@"EventReminder"];
}

- (void)sendNotificationToReactNative
{
    [self sendEventWithName:@"EventReminder" body:@{@"name": @"name"}];
}
```

and while initing the function

```
RNNotification *notification = [RNNotification allocWithZone: nil];
[notification sendNotificationToReactNative]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your emitter class like this

```
[[self.bridge moduleForClass:[RNNotification class]] sendNotificationToReactNative];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solution to to send event from `iOS` to `React Native`

> RNEventEmitter.m

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
  #import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

   @interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RNEventEmitter, RCTEventEmitter)
    RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(supportedEvents)
   @end
```

> RNEventEmitter.swift

```
 import Foundation

 @objc(RNEventEmitter)
  open class RNEventEmitter: RCTEventEmitter {

     public static var emitter: RCTEventEmitter!

     override init() {
     super.init()
     RNEventEmitter.emitter = self
   }

    open override func supportedEvents() -> [String] {
      ["onReady", "onPending", "onFailure"]      // etc.
    }
}
```

> Your file from where you are going to `emit event` add below line

```
  RNEventEmitter.emitter.sendEvent(withName: "onReady", body: [["status":"Connected","data":["name":dev?.name,"deviceId":dev?.identifier]]]);
```

> React Native file

```
    const emitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.RNEventEmitter)
```

> In your Bridgin-Header file import

```
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
```

> In your useEffect

```
emitter.addListener('onReady', (data: any) => {
        console.log("addListener", data);
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    });
```